# ASP.Net Session POCO Collection Property

Tags: asp.net, session, persistence, poco

I am persisting an object to Session in ASP.Net. This property has a nested collection property, which is a `List<Type>`:

```
public class Model {
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public List<Model> Models { get; set; }
}
```

When I add a `Model` to the `Models` property, the item exists until the page is disposed. The nested property is not being persisted to `Session`.

```
var model = Session["Model"] as Model;
model.Models.Add(new Model() { ID = "foo" });
```

What is the best way to ensure that the property changes are persisted into session?

Answer (score 1):

```
var model = Session["Model"] as Model;
model.Models.Add(new Model() { ID = "foo" });
Session["Model"] = model;
```